# Civilization 6 - Relics - what happen when you run out of Relic slots?

Tags: civilization-6

I'm playing as Poland and I got Kandy as a city right next door. Since I'm suzerain I'm getting Relics for Nature Wonders.

Question is this: when I get a Relic but have no slot for it what happens with the Relic? Goes into storage? Disappears? I can't find definitive answer to this after searching the internet... I know one can have quite a few of them, but most threads concentrate on maximizing Relics. I'm pretty early into game and looking at at least 6-7 relics with scouting I have out there already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was this one time that I had an apostle with Martyr promotion - you get a relic when this apostle dies in combat. I lost him in theology combat and I had no appropriate slot for the relic. The end result that I can assure you is:

- **You won't get any relic** out of the event.
- You won't have the option to move your existing art to make room for the new relic, etc

In my case, the apostle died and the game notified me about losing a unit but there was no notification about wasting a relic opportunity whatsoever as far as I can remember. The game just proceeds as if that apostle has no promotion.

When I reloaded the game, made some room for the relic and put the apostle into his doom again, I got the relic.

This was quite some time ago and my scenario is about Martyr promotion rather than a bonus from city state but I believe the game would proceed the same way for both scenarios. I encourage you to test it out and share it to the community :)

Comment: This lines up with my own observations. However may I propose a small change? I believe that the relic is granted, but due to lack of slot it will go into >/dev/null.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/12098/what-does-outputting-to-dev-null-accomplish-in-bash-scripts
Might be important if there's a hard limit of relics in the game. But the end result is the same, I agree, as well as with the notion that Martyr promotion and City-State ability are essentially the same for our purposes here.